# SQL Server date vs smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of tables which consolidate data on different levels: quarterly, hourly, daily and monthly. Apart from that there's a base table which contains the "raw" data as well, this one contains some extra columns. The consolidated tables all have the same columns.

The base, quarterly and hourly tables make use of a column of type `smalldatetime` to timestamp the data. This column will also be available in the hourly and daily tables, but of course I won't need the time aspect here.

For the sake of simplicity I want to use the smalldatetime data type here also, but maybe it's better for performance to use a date data type for the column?

Is there a really big difference between the types when it comes down to performance?

Comment: SMALLDATETIME is deprecated in SQL Server 2008. Use DATE,TIME or DATETIME2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Well my question will eventually be the same then: datetime vs date

Comment: @dportas: smalldatetime is *not* deprecated: it's a standard type in ANSI too.

Comment: @gbn, where did you get the information that smalldatetime is a standard type in "ANSI"? Which version of the SQL Standard are you referring to? It's not in the ISO/IEC 9075 2003 docs. I don't have all the earlier versions with me right now but I'm pretty sure the standard date time type has been TIMESTAMP and never SMALLDATETIME which was a Sybase invention. SMALLDATETIME is deprecated by Microsoft as per the link I already posted.

Comment: @dportas: this is what BOL says when deprecated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx. You're correct about the standard though for smalldatetime

Comment: link suggested by @sqlvogel clearly says **smalldatetime is not ANSI or ISO 8601 compliant** but surprisingly I'm seeing its availability in SQL Server 2012 version as well. The link says it is applicable to _SQL Server 2008 onwards_ but says nothing about deprecation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to use the smallest data type that you need.  You shouldn't use varchar(max) or even varchar(10) to store a 2 character state abbreviation.

In the same sense, if you just need the Date (e.g. 4/11/2001) then use the Date type and not the DateTime type.

While it might not be a huge gain in performance (DateTime is 5 bytes larger than Date.)It can start adding up if you have multiple fields and/or multiple rows.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Found a good article on the subject as well: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1616. Not really about performance but it's a comparison of the different solution for storing dates.

Answer (score 6):

Various data types have various [size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) which **affects** size of data/indexes, which is more important than query performance (I/O cost).

On the other hand converting between data types could be costly. Moreover implicit conversion between various data types can be wrong/unexpected.

I would keep one type of date (4 bytes `smalldatetime` in this case) if you JOIN between tables on date columns or if not keep the smallest possible date type -- `smalldatetime` for storing hours and quarters and `date` for *pure* dates.

Answer (score 1):

Range

SmallDateTime: 1 - jan - 1900 to 6 - jun - 2079 
DateTime : 1 - jan -1753 to 31 - Dec - 9999

Precision

SmallDateTime: Minute 
DateTime : Three hundredth of a second(3.33)

Storage

SmallDateTime: 4 Bytes 
DateTime : 8 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the case of `smalldatetime`, it has for me caused trouble when using bcp (bulk copy) utility for export/import operations. BCP import appears to not like `smalldatetime` fields (at least as they are exported by BCP). Version as late as SQL Server 2008 and using "native" format in bcp. Therefore I will be using `datetime` for my work in the future because I like being able to use bcp for moving data around.

Answer (score 0):

check this, too:

when you have to convert from varchar(max) into a datetime:

```
declare @s varchar(max)
set @s = '2018-06-01 00:00:01'
select CONVERT(smalldatetime, @s )
select CONVERT(datetime,@s )
```

results into this

```
2018-06-01 00:00:00
2018-06-01 00:00:01.000
```

this one second past midnight vanished when converted to smalldatetime